# How to use a variable from ngfor in ngif?

Tags: html, angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I'm encounter a problem while using a variable from `*ngFor` inside an `*ngIf` :

```
<li *ngFor="let event of enum ; let i = index">
  <textarea pInputTextarea autoResize="autoResize" [(ngModel)]=x[i] placeholder="xxx" formControlName=desc{{i}}></textarea>

  <div class="alert" *ngIf="!rForm.controls['desc'" +{{ i }}+ "].valide">
     {{ i }}
  </div>
</li>
```

I tried to use `ngif` alone and it's working fine :

```
<div class="alert" *ngIf=i> *****</div>
```

I am able to see the 0 .. 1 .. 2 .. in the DOM.

What is the proper way to do a concatenation in the template?

Comment: You want to do concatenation of what ?

Comment: I would try something like `"*ngIf="!rForm.controls['desc' + i ].valid">`

Comment: that's it , it worked , thxs mate

Comment: try not use [(ngModel)] and formControlName in the same tag (formControlName is ReactiveForm, [(ngModel)] is template driven Form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li *ngFor="let event of enum ; let i = index">
  <textarea pInputTextarea autoResize="autoResize" [(ngModel)]=x[i] placeholder="xxx" formControlName=desc{{i}}></textarea>

  <div class="alert" *ngIf="!rForm.controls['desc'" + i + "].valide">
     {{ i }}
  </div>
</li>
```

I do not need to be enclosed in interpolation directive `{{}}` because it's not string interpolation which you are trying to achieve. Treat it as a variable and use + as you would in with a normal variable.

Hope this helps!!